# Select div from string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have string that contains some div's how to get one of them by id ?

**EDIT**

I'm using right click selection plugin, so when i select a div .

```
 $("#first #second").contextMenu({
        menu: 'myMenu'
    },
        function(action, el, pos) {
      switch (action) {
            case "do":
                {
```

and the selection is basicley

```
$(el).html()
```

So this is the code that contains the html that is in #second, but the #second isn't one div , it is a'lot of divs with that id, and i want when i click on that div to select certain id and get it's context . Is there a easyer way ?

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, so we can see how you are getting the string containing the divs.

Comment: A string? So you're not working with the DOM? Do you want the answer in the form of a regular expression? I guess I'm asking, please provide more detail. Oh, and welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: In other words, do you need help parsing a string?

Comment: -1 You need to provide some more detail if you hope to get an answer. For example a sample HTML fragment would be a good start. Note: you can edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can wrap `el` and traverse from it, like this:

```
$(el).find('.something-else').blah(); // ...
```

`el` is not a string, it's a DOM element.

Some of your confusion might stem from writing `$(el).html()`. If you were debugging with that, it'd look like a string because you were extracting the actual HTML held within the DOM element you had in hand.

Answer (score 4):

You can have jquery interpret a string as a set of tags like this:

```
$(htmlstring);
```

So something like this might work:

```
$("<div><div id='test'></div></div>").find("#test");
```

**Edit:**
Now with the updated question this is of course not what you want.

You can't have more than one element with the same id. IDs are supposed to be unique identifiers.

Comment: well since the OP has changed the question it looks like we both wasted our time :) but for reference `filter` is better than `find` here as `filter` doesn't require an outer container.

Comment: and i'll +1 you anyway as you made a good answer before the question was changed.

Comment: true, +1 for that. it's funny to see the answers, all somehow trying to interpret the question which turned out to be completely different ;-)

Comment: +1 for using `filter`, saved me, even though not relevant to question it was relevant to my google search ;)

Comment: +1 because although it doesn't answer the question, it answers exactly what I was looking for. Saved me a lot of time :-)